# Remove parentheses from tag cloud count

Tags: tags

I am trying to remove the parentheses from the tag cloud widget and add in `<span class="post_count"> </span>` in place of it.

Currently I have not been having any luck. I have this working for categories just fine but not sure why it won't work for the tag cloud count.

```
function categories_postcount_filter ($variable) {
$variable = str_replace('(', '<span class="post_count"> ', $variable);
$variable = str_replace(')', ' </span>', $variable);
return $variable;
}
add_filter('wp_list_categories','categories_postcount_filter');
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks so much!

Ponte

Comment: In WP 4.8 there is a checkbox to toggle the count in the admin area. Prior to WP 4.8 there was no counter displayed for the default tags widget.

Comment: Hi Dave. Exactly. I am trying to remove the parentheses that show when they do have that option checked to show the count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is an example output of an tag cloud widget element (wp4.8):

```
<a href="http://localhost/wp-beta-test/tag/handcrafted/" class="tag-cloud-link tag-link-327 tag-link-position-22" style="font-size: 8pt;" aria-label="handcrafted (2 items)">handcrafted<span class="tag-link-count"> (2)</span></a>
```

as you can see, the widget outputs some aria lable also using parentheses, which interferes with a simple string replace.
the tag number including the parentheses is also already wrapped in a span.

for example, try to use:

```
function tagcloud_postcount_filter ($variable) {
$variable = str_replace('<span class="tag-link-count"> (', ' <span class="post_count"> ', $variable);
$variable = str_replace(')</span>', '</span>', $variable);
return $variable;
}
add_filter('wp_tag_cloud','tagcloud_postcount_filter');
```

Comment: Hi Michael! This worked great. I appreciate you taking the time to help me out. Thank you.